# ¿Cual forma es mas eficiente para hacer un if con varias condiciones?

Tags: python, condiciones

¿Que forma es mas eficiente para hacer un condicional if donde se necesiten validar varias condiciones?

```
if a>0 and b>0:
    pass
```

o tal vez

```
if a>0:
    if b>0:
        pass
```

Comment: La verdad, no creo que haya diferencia significativa. Y no es el tipo de optimizaciones por las que uno debería preocuparse.

Comment: Tu pregunta parece basada en opiniones Pero por lo que veo ¿Para que hacer una concadenacion de ifs? Si se pueden unir en uno solo `a>0 and b>0`

Comment: @CandidMoe lo pones como respuesta?

Comment: @gbianchi. Sospecho que abulafia ya está escribiendo una.

Comment: Las expresiones lógicas se evaluan de izquierda a derecha hasta tener certeza del resultado final. Entonces, `if a and b`: evaluara `b` sólo si `a` resulta `True`. Por tanto, ambas formas son equivalentes.

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace. Gracias por la corrección.

Comment: En programación de microcontroladores dado que los recursos (procesador, ram, eprom) son muy limitados se trata de optimizar en todos los sentidos el costo de los algoritmos, se utiliza mucho algo conocido como “branchless programming” que resulta menos costoso computacionalmente siempre y cuando se aplique bien, puedes investigar del tema y ver cómo lo puedes implementar. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

En este caso específico que planteas es más 'practico'

```py
if a>0 and b>0
    pass
```

Ya que el resultado se basa en que las dos variables sean mayores a cero y no se plantean escenarios en donde `a<0` o `b<0`.
Hablando de eficiencia no hay mucha diferencia.

Comment: Tienes razón, de esa forma es más practico y se ahorra líneas de código.